# Confirm quit in Xcode

Tags: xcode, exit

How to set Xcode to ask before quitting it? It happens that I accidentally press command-q, and it closes all windows. Is there a setting to prevent this, and pop up a confirmation dialog before closing everything?

Comment: No, I don't think so. This is OS X. It assumes you know what you are doing. Train not to press cmd-q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know is a plugin for Xcode called [XQuit](https://github.com/StefanLage/XQuit).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the key binding from the menu Xcode > Preferences..., then click the 'Key Bindings' and change the value for 'Quit Xcode' to blank or something less prone to be press like <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.